# Should I use post requests over get requests?

Tags: http

So basically I am working on an API that has authenticated routes and in order to access the route, you must pass a token and a userId. The way I currently have this implemented is the token in an Authorization header and the userId in the req body.

However, I find myself sending post requests for methods that are really meant for get requests such as fetching a user's search history but since the route is protected, I need to send the token and userId which forces me to use a post request instead.

This has made it so that all of the typical get requests are post requests. I read that post requests are slower than get requests but since the request body is so small, I don't think performance is really an issue.

But still I just want to make sure: **Is it appropriate/acceptable to use post requests instead of get requests?**

I know that it obviously works, but is it proper API "architecture"?

Thank you!

Comment: I would say it's not proper. Usually get/post/put/delete are used to add some meaning to each call, making it easier to quickly determine what the call does. As for a solution, for basic auth, the string `<username>:<password>` is b64 encoded and sent in the auth header. You could use that same system to pass both your user id and the token in the auth header. This would also make your API easily usable by any client software that supports basic auth.